# Delete Specific Rows from a NumPy Array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays:

```
A

[['12345' 45 100]
 ['12345' 29 100]
 ['45451' 23 0]
 ['56789' 45 450]
 ['56789' 56 50]
 ['56567' 5 500]
 ['89321' 15 0]
 ['90234' 43 40]
 ['90234' 55 0]
 ['99843' 18 5500]]

B

[['12345']
 ['90234']
 ['45451']
 ['56789']
 ['89321']]
```

I need to leave in array B only rows where elements equals the elements from 1 column in array A and the 3rd column contains value "0". Basically, these are '45451' and '89321'.

I have the next code:

```
for ind1 in range(len(A)):  
    for ind2 in range(len(B)):
        if (A[ind1][0] == B[ind2]) and (A[ind1][2] > 0):
           B = np.delete(B, ind2, axis=0)
B
```

I've got the following error message:

**IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4**

I suppose it's something with array dimensions but can't figure out. Would appreciate if you can fix the code :)

Tried to change the conditions

Comment: Please specify clearly the conditions for output and what your output should look like.

Comment: I'm comparing the elements in 1st column of two arrays. If an element from array A equals an element from array B and the 3rd column of array A contains bigger then 0 number - then I need to delete this element from array B.

The right result is:
B[array]:

'45451' 
'89321'

Comment: full error please.  Which index is the problem?  Be careful when deleting rows from B.  Its size changes!  I suspect you aren't paying close attention to the changes.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
if (A[ind1][0] == B[ind2]) and (A[ind1][2] > 0):
```

It should be as

```
if (A[ind1][:, :1] == B[ind2]) and (A[ind1][2] > 0):
```

In the 2nd line where the changes made, you are trying to match the first column in array A to array B, this should work

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(
    [[12345, 45, 100],
     [12345, 29, 100],
     [45451, 23, 0],
     [56789, 45, 450],
     [56789, 56, 50],
     [56567, 5, 500],
     [89321, 15, 0],
     [90234, 43, 40],
     [90234, 55, 0],
     [99843, 18, 5500]])
b = np.array(
    [[12345],
     [90234],
     [45451],
     [56789],
     [89321]])
print(*b[np.isin(b, a[a[:,2]==0][:,0])])
```